# Solving a congruence equation using a corollary of Fermats Little Theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have the congruence equation $$4x=11 \mod{19}$$
How can I solve this using $$x\equiv a^{p-2}b\mod{p} $$

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $4 \cdot 5 \equiv 1 \pmod {19}$

Comment: Well... you have the solution already, no? It's $4^{17}\cdot 11$. Or simplified, using that $4=2^2$, it's $2^{16}\cdot 11$

Comment: Are you asking how to (efficiently) compute $4^{17}\pmod {19},\,$ or something else?

Comment: yes, using that corollary

Comment: We can use repeated squaring, e.g. $4$ squares yields the $16$th power $4\overset{\large x^2}\to -3\to 9\to 5\to \color{#c00}{6 \equiv 4^{\large 16}}$ so $\,4^{\large 17} \!\equiv 4(\color{#c00}{4^{\large 16}}\!)\equiv 4(\color{#c00}6)\equiv 5\pmod{\!19}\ \ $

Comment: I am completely stuck still.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have
$$ax \equiv 11 \mod 19 \mbox{ with } a = 4$$
and you would like to multiply this congruence with the inverse $a^{-1} \mod 19$.

Little Fermat tells you:
$$a^{18} \equiv 1 \mod 19 \Rightarrow a^{-1} \equiv a^{17} \mod 19$$
But this is not necessarily the most efficient way to calculate $a^{-1} \mod 19$.

Here Will Jagy's comment comes into play:
$$4\cdot 5 = 20 = 19 + 1 \Rightarrow 4^{17} \equiv 4^{-1} \equiv 5 \mod 19$$
Now you can solve your congruence
$$4x \equiv 11 \mod 19 \Leftrightarrow 4^{-1}\cdot 4x \equiv 4^{-1}\cdot 11 \mod 19 
\Leftrightarrow \color{blue}{x} \equiv 5\cdot 11 \color{blue}{\equiv 17 \mod 19}$$